# ajax call Sentinel::check() always return null

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.3, sentinel

I using Sentinel package, Everything is fine, But when I want call Sentinel::check() and Sentinel::getUser() using ajax, it return null.
help me please :(

```
$currentUser = Sentinel::getUser();
$my_id = $currentUser->id;
return $my_id;
```

Comment: This is a bug in the package.

Comment: I asked it in github. 
https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/issues/354

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another way.
First add user's info into a session after logging

```
Session::put('city_id', $currentUser->city_id);
```

then goto app/Http/Kernel.php and active session on rest api routes

```
'api' => [ \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class, \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, 'throttle:60,1', 'bindings', ],
```

and use it in ajax call.